# In Laravel 5.1 blade templates, how can I use @yield without the extra space added at the end?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

I have a blade template `master.blade` that has the following code:

```
<title>@yield('meta-title')</title>
```

And then in any views that extend this template, the data can be passed in like this:

```
@section('meta-title')My Meta Title @stop
```

However, this ALWAYS adds a space at the end. If I remove the space in the code so it looks like the following, then it will not recognise the `@stop` and the page breaks:

```
@section('meta-title')My Meta Title@stop
```

Is there a way to achieve this functionality (dynamically inject content into the header without any spacing before or after) either using @yield or some other way?

[Blade Template Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#template-inheritance)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pass a second parameter to `@section`, like so: `@section('meta-title', 'My Meta Title')`, no need for `@stop`

It is indeed in the docs: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#template-inheritance

Comment: Oh my god! I have read those docs 1000 times and never saw that! Thank you.

Comment: How do I solve this issue when I need to @overwrite the @section?